# Erro PHP: Too many connections

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou recebendo algumas mensagens da minha aplicação, de muitas conexões em execução.

> ```
> PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (08004/1040): Too many connections in /home/rmour123/public_html/admin/conexao.php on line 31
> ```

Abaixo a forma que implementei:

```
    public static function getInstance() {
       if (!isset(self::$db)) {
         try{
             self::$db = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DBNAME);
         } catch (Exception $e) {
             print "Erro: " . $e->getMessage(); 
         }
       }
       return self::$db;  
    }
```

A pergunta é a seguinte, será que estou com alguma rotina lenta e que está travando as outras conexões e assim atingindo o limite estabelecido no MYSQL(Neste caso 150 conexões)? Ou tem mais alguma coisa que não observei?

Comment: Vc usa servidor compartilhado?

Comment: Oi @dvd, eu uso o serviço da hostgator do mais simples. Além de ser compartilhado, eu tenho 2 bases de dados, uma do wordpress e outra da aplicação no mesmo server.

Comment: Pode ser isso. O servidor do banco tem um limite e não está sendo suficiente.

Comment: Qual seria o paleativo? Melhorar a performance das queries, para liberar mais rápido as conexões em uso?

Comment: Se vc tah fechando as conexões depois de usa-las?

Comment: Não, eu fecho somente o statement após a utilização na função prepare().